# Spring Data JPA - Specifications join

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have specification:

```
final String text = "%text%";
final Specifications<PersonEntity> spec = Specifications.where(
    (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(builder.lower(root.join(PersonEntity_.addresses, JoinType.LEFT).get(AddressEntity_.addressLine1)), text)
).or(
    (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(builder.lower(root.join(PersonEntity_.addresses, JoinType.LEFT).get(AddressEntity_.addressLine2)), text)
).or(
    (root, query, builder) -> builder.like(builder.lower(root.join(PersonEntity_.addresses, JoinType.LEFT).get(AddressEntity_.city)), text)
)
```

After using:

```
personRepository.findAll(spec);
```

In logs, I see, that JPA create a query where it joins addresses three times instead of once.

How can I write a Specification where addresses will be joined only once?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I changed it to:

```
Specifications.where(
    (root, query, builder) -> {
        final Join<PersonEntity, AddressEntity> addresses = root.join(PersonEntity_.address, JoinType.LEFT);
        return builder.or(
            builder.like(builder.lower(addresses.get(AddressEntity_.addressLine1)), text),
            builder.like(builder.lower(addresses.get(AddressEntity_.addressLine2)), text),
            builder.like(builder.lower(addresses.get(AddressEntity_.code)), text),
        );
    }
);
```

Now, it is joining only once.

Comment: This is JPA metamodel. If you have problems with understanding how it works, feel free to ask *new* question on SO

Comment: Yeah Thanks !. Will you please guide me for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167639/multi-column-search-using-specifications-spring-data-jpa-within-associated-entit ?

Comment: Could you tell me what dependency you use which allows you to simply reference your model attributes by appending the underscore to your model's name?

Comment: This is JPA metamodel, check it here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html